# while loop does not go infinitely but for loop does?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The definition of hasNext() is "Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input."

When I put **standardInput.hasNext()** in for-loop, the program runs toward infinity. But if i Put it in while-loop it does not run to infinity.
Where is the differenc between these two programs and why one of them work and another not?

for-loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vocabulary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner standardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; standardInput.hasNext(); i++){
            System.out.print(i);

        }

    }

}
```

while-loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        Scanner standardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double sum = 0;
        
        while(standardInput.hasNext()) {
            double nextNumber = standardInput.nextDouble();
            sum += nextNumber;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sum is " + sum + ".");

        }
 }
```

I read the definition, but still cannot understand why one program works but another not

Comment: I honestly can't reproduce and understand how you think your second program with the while loop works correct and doesn't result in an infinite loop. It also keeps asking for input forever and the only difference is you can get it to crash with a java.util.InputMismatchException if you enter something that isn't a number, but i really don't see how you ever would get it to reach the `System.out.println("The Sum is " + sum + ".");` line

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS, I do not understand what you mean? Do you mean the second program does not work?

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS, the second with a while loop makes the sum of numbers you type in. In order to end the program, just type Strg + D or control + D. After that the program gives you the correct result. There is not infinite loop but in for-loop.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: The two programs behave differently because their code is not equivalant.

In the while loop, you get the next token by calling `standardInput.nextDouble()`. This changes the result of `standardInput.hasNext()` on each iteration.

On the other hand, the for loop version never gets the next token, so the value returned by `hasNext()` never changes.

Answer (score 2):

In `for...loop` you do not read `standardInput` to get it, but you check it in the codition; you do it in the `while...loop`.

To fix it you should add scanner reading inside the loop;

```java
for(int i = 0; standardInput.hasNext(); i++){
    String str = standardInput.next(); // add reading
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because these lines of code only check if there is to be read but not actually reading the file, thus, not advancing the file pointer.

```
for(int i = 0; standardInput.hasNext(); i++){
    System.out.print(i);

}
```

While these lines of code actually read a type double using the Scanner object.

```
while(standardInput.hasNext()) {
    double nextNumber = standardInput.nextDouble();
    sum += nextNumber;
 }
```